# Difference between funcunit and jasmine?

Tags: testing, jasmine, funcunit

Hi! Can anyone give the exact difference between FuncUnit and Jasmine unit test frameworks for Javascript. I went to the Jasmine Framework and found it little easy but I need to find the exact differences between these two frameworks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference I can see is that [FuncUnit](http://funcunit.com/) is a unit test framework, but [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) is a framework for building using the [Behaviour-Driven Development](http://behaviour-driven.org/) methodology, not specifically for writing unit tests.

Comment: Can u please elaborate? I went through funcunit and i found that funcunit can test drag and drop as well as pop up events.Is it possible with jasmine ? If yes can u please give me the reference?

Comment: Jasmine is intended as a design tool rather than simply a test tool. The links I provided are to the homepages for the two projects, the necessary docs should be there.